# Which approach using window variables in Scene Delegate is better?

Tags: window

var window: UIWindow?

func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

```
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    
    let vc = ViewController()
    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window.rootViewController = vc
    self.window = window  
}
```

Or

var window: UIWindow?

func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

```
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    
    let vc = ViewController()
   window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window.?makeKeyAndVisible()
    window?.rootViewController = vc
}
```

Which approach is better, I prefer first, Am I right?